# How to draw AC equivalent circuit for low cut-off frequency?

Tags: bjt

I have the following circuit with me and I wish to draw AC equivalent circuit for low cut-off frequency to determine the dominant low cut-off frequency. I am confused, especially for the capacitor C3 as I’m having trouble to simplify this portion.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the bottom leg of a C3 capacitor is connected to GND. And the upper leg is connected between RB1 and RB2. Thus, your equivalent circuit is wrong.

Comment: And to be able to find the C3 time constants you need to find the resistance seen by a C3 capacitor. In this case, it will be \$\tau \approx C_3(R_{B1}||R_{B2})\$. Thus the corner frequency \$F \approx \frac{0.16}{C_3 (R_{B1}||R_{B2})} \approx 266.7Hz \$